# Show icon on datagrid when cell is selected

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to show one icon in the rowheader (row selected indicator) in my datagrid when one cell is selected. I got it with  DataGridSelectionUnit.Row and RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridRow,1) as you can see in the bellow picture,  but I need it working with  DataGridSelectionUnit.Cell;

[image]

I guess the trick is in the binding, but don't know which property must be linked to the binding:

```
Binding bindingVisibility = new Binding()
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelected"),
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridCell),1 ),
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
            Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter()
        };
        elemFactory.SetBinding(VisibilityProperty, bindingVisibility);
```

Thanks!

Regards

Xabi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propagating the selection state from cells to rows is a bit tricky, but possible under most circumstances.

This solution proposes an attached property to handle the cell->row selection (code below).

Basic idea: whenever selected cells change, use the cellInfo item to determine the current position within the visual tree, walk up to the row and update the row as needed.

The handling has to be enabled on the `DataGrid` with the `DataGridSelection.PropagateCellSelection` attached property, then for each `DataGridRow`, the `DataGridSelection.IsSelected` attached property can be used.

The following code sample would change the row header background color to green, you can replace the setter with anything you want. `xmlns:local` points to the namespace, where `DataGridSelection` is defined.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="Cell" local:DataGridSelection.PropagateCellSelection="True">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:DataGridSelection.IsSelected),RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Attached property code

```
public static class DataGridSelection
{
    // The DataGridSelection.IsSelected property will be maintained on DataGridRow, if
    // DataGridSelection.PropagateCellSelection is set to true on the DataGrid.

    public static bool GetIsSelected(DataGridRow obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
    }

    private static void SetIsSelected(DataGridRow obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsSelectedPropertyKey, value);
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsSelectedPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridSelection), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = IsSelectedPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;


    // The DataGridSelection.PropagateCellSelection property enables the mechanism of maintaining
    // DataGridSelection.IsSelected state on DataGridRow

    public static bool GetPropagateCellSelection(DataGrid obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(PropagateCellSelectionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPropagateCellSelection(DataGrid obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PropagateCellSelectionProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropagateCellSelectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PropagateCellSelection", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridSelection), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(PropagateCellSelectionChanged)));


    private static void PropagateCellSelectionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is DataGrid dg)) return;

        // Add or remove the event handler that handles the propagation from cell selection
        // to DataGridSelection.IsSelected on DataGridRow

        if (true.Equals(e.NewValue))
        {
            dg.SelectedCellsChanged -= DataGridCellSelectionChangedHandler;
            dg.SelectedCellsChanged += DataGridCellSelectionChangedHandler;
        }
        else
        {
            dg.SelectedCellsChanged -= DataGridCellSelectionChangedHandler;
        }
    }

    // Determine rows to add / remove the selected state whenever cell selection changes
    private static void DataGridCellSelectionChangedHandler(object s, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(s is DataGrid dg)) return;

        var removeRows = RowsFromCellInfos(e.RemovedCells);
        var selectedRows = RowsFromCellInfos(dg.SelectedCells);

        removeRows.ExceptWith(selectedRows);

        foreach (var row in removeRows)
            SetIsSelected(row, false);
        foreach (var row in selectedRows)
            SetIsSelected(row, true);
    }

    private static ISet<DataGridRow> RowsFromCellInfos(IEnumerable<DataGridCellInfo> cells)
    {
        var rows = new HashSet<DataGridRow>();
        foreach (var cellInfo in cells)
        {
            var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
            var row = GetParent<DataGridRow>(cellContent);
            if (row != null) rows.Add(row);
        }
        return rows;
    }

    // Helper method for tree traversal
    private static T GetParent<T>(DependencyObject d) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        while (d != null && !(d is T))
            d = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d);

        return d as T;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `SelectionUnit="Cell"`, the selected row handling gets a little "difficult" and can't be done using XAML only:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid SelectionUnit="Cell" 
          DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridCell_OnSelected" 
          DataGridCell.Unselected="DataGridCell_OnUnselected">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <ContentControl x:Key="RowHeaderContent" x:Shared="False">
      <Image Source="[path to image]" />
    </ContentControl>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void DataGridCell_OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = e.Source as DataGrid;
  var selectedCell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;
  object selectedRowItem = selectedCell.DataContext;
  var selectedRow = (DataGridRow) dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedRowItem);
  selectedRow.Header = dataGrid.Resources["RowHeaderContent"];
}

private void DataGridCell_OnUnselected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = e.Source as DataGrid;
  var selectedCell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;
  object selectedRowItem = selectedCell.DataContext;

  // Check if there is still any cell of the same row selected
  if (dataGrid.SelectedCells.Any(cellInfo => cellInfo.Item == selectedRowItem))
  {
    return;
  }

  var selectedRow = (DataGridRow) dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedRowItem);
  selectedRow.Header = null;
}
```

Comment: Did you actually test this with `SelectionUnit="Cell"`? Not working for me

Comment: Sorry, the example was indeed targeting the row based default selection style. I have adjusted the answer to provide a cell based solution.

Comment: Much better... now the remaining problems relate to multi-select (like, when you first select 2 cells in one row, then reduce the selection to one cell so you get an `Unselected` event while there is still a selected cell in the row) and we don't know whether the question is concerned with this

Comment: I have updated the answer (`DataGridCell_OnUnselected`). Also note that the resource used for the row header content must be marked with `x:Shared="False"`. Otherwise there will be only a single item at the time visible. As a result only one row can render this content (no multi-references to a single instance are allowed - an object is only allowed to be added once to the visual tree). `x:Shared="False"` forces the XAML parser to create cloned instances. I have updated the example accordingly.